# Difference between git merge and git fetch?

Tags: git

What is the difference between 'git merge' and 'git fetch'?
I have some problems with these two commands.
I don't know when I should use one or the other.

Comment: `git fetch` updates your local repository with commits that have been added to the server since your last fetch, while `git merge` will try to combine two parallel development paths. They're completely different. Have you considered reading one of the many tutorials on git, or the Pro Git book (available [online](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2) for free)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

**UPDATE** - Good grief, my merge diagrams have been wrong this whole time.  A merge doesn't move the "other" branch's ref...

---

`git fetch` is about retrieving data from a remote repository.

`git merge` is about combining work from multiple lines of work (usually local branches, but see below).

`git pull` (I know you didn't ask about `pull` but bear with me) is a shorthand that retrieves data from the remote like `fetch`, then `merge`s into your current branch the corresponding line of work from the remote (if there is one; the "tracking information" determines this.)

So for example, say you have a remote repo with a single branch (`master`) containing 5 commits.

```
'origin' repo

A --- B --- C --- D --- E <--(master)
```

A while ago you had cloned this repo; at the time only the first commit (`A`) was in it.  You then created a new branch (`branch1`) and did a little work, creating a new commit (`L`) on that branch.  Lastly, you had pulled in changes from the remote; more on how that works later, but for now let's just say that you updated your `master` to include `B`.

```
local repo

A --- B <--(master)(origin/master)
 \
  L <-- (branch1)
```

Note that in addition to your local branch refs (`master` and `branch1`) you have a remote branch reference (`origin/master`) which, for now, happens to be the same as `master`.

Now if you want to update your local repo to contain all the data from the origin, but *without merging anything*, you would say

```
git fetch
```

and then you have

```
        C --- D --- E <--(origin/master)
       /
A --- B <--(master)
 \
  L <-- (branch1)
```

That's a fetch - just get the data from the remote.

The main reason you'd explicitly ask for a `merge` would be to combine your work from `branch1` with your `master`.  So

```
git checkout master
git merge branch1
```

(then possibly resolve any conflicts) and you now have

```
        C --- D --- E <--(origin/master)
       /
A --- B --- M <--(master)
 \         /
  L ------- <--(branch1)
```

(Under some circumstances - where only one of the branches contains changes that aren't in the other - a merge can be done via "fast forward"; but that doesn't apply here since each branch had changes - i.e. the branches had *diverged*.  Also there's another technique called *rebasing* that can sometimes be used to combine branches; but that's another can of worms...)

So that's the difference between `fetch` and `merge` - very different operations that do different things.  But I also mentioned `pull` which kind of combines the two.  If you do a `pull`, first it pulls changes from the remote (in case you haven't fully updated with `fetch`), and then if the current branch has a corresponding remote branch, it merges them.

```
# still on master
git pull
```

gives something like

```
        C --- D --- E --- N <--(master)(origin/master)
       /                 /
A --- B --------------- M 
 \                     /
  L ------------------- <--(branch1)
```

(Note that while I *normally* draw these diagrams such that the "straight line" coming into a merge is the "first parent", in this case that was getting to be troublesome for `N`; but this does show the general commit topology...)

Back when I talked about "pulling in changes" to get `B` into your local repo, it likely would've been done using `git pull`

Answer (score 2):

`git fetch` will download the source tree to check for changes, and `git merge` joins your current branch with another branch.